# Firefox not loading certain background images when served via Apache, no matter what I try

Tags: html, css, image, apache

I have a really simple piece of CSS which is applying a background image to `<li>` elements

```
.icon-facebook { background: url("./images/icon_facebook.png") no-repeat; }
```

This works fine when I view it locally, without a web server, i.e. by double-clicking the .html file.

But as soon as I serve the same page via Apache - whether on localhost or a production server - the background images disappear.

- Other background images on the page work fine - and all have identical (relative) paths.
- Specifying an absolute path to the background-images does not work either.
- Renaming the files did not work.
- The images can be displayed just fine if navigated to directly in the browser.
- Monitoring Apache's access log, the browser doesn't even attempt to request the images (!), *even if an absolute URL is supplied in the CSS*.

When I inspect the `<li>` Firebug says "could not load the given URL" but when I copy and paste the background-image URL straight from the CSS in Firebug into a new tab - guess what? It works.

I have a `<div>` on the same page with a different background image from the same folder which works just fine. When I replace its filename with one of my "problem" files I notice it isn't displayed any more.

The images in question are 20x20px PNGs (but I tried JPGs too).

All other browsers work fine.

This is truly driving me crazy.

Comment: Have you tried it with an image from an external domain? such as google's logo?

Comment: Yes and it works. It also works with another image file from the same document. It's as if this set of images in particular are causing an issue.

Comment: Can you show a live example? Have you tried emptying the browser cache just to exclude the possibility that this was a one-time fluke?

Comment: Check if your image is an RGB, not a CMYK?

Comment: What is the url of the page, and what is the full url of the image? The `./` is a little weird to see on the web.

Comment: I just renamed one of the images and it's now working. The original filename was in the format `icon_foo_bar.png` and I changed it to `icon.png` which worked, then `icon-foo-bar.png` which worked, and now `icon_fooz_bar.png` (i.e. I just added a "z") and it works! As soon as I change it back to the original filename it craps out again. What the hell? @Pekka웃 it's definitely not a cache issue as I've flushed it more times than my toilet.

Comment: This is unreal. I renamed all of the icons and now none are working again. This is genuinely unreal. @SeanFujiwara I wish I could link to the page but it's a commercial projects which has to be kept private! :'(

Comment: For those following, please see my answer. It was Adblock Plus, which explains why some filenames worked and others did not. Unreal.

Comment: I think you should use `url("../images/icon_facebook.png")` (two dots ../ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unbelievable. Truly unbelievable.**

The culprit was Adblock Plus, which I had installed on Firefox but not any other browser. It was interpreting the names and/or class names of the background images as being either advertisements or social media annoyances, and therefore silently blocking them.

I had previously added my production domain to its white list, but when it changed I forgot to update it.

That explains why some image filenames worked (e.g. `icon_f.png` whereas others - `icon_fb.png` or `icon_facebook.png` - did not).

Let this be a lesson - do not run any kind of addons on your development browser.

I was ready to cry... and think I will now. Cry for my stupidity.

Thank you to all for your input.

Comment: I've been caught by that before. It's just easier to put up with adverts than keep wondering if Adblock is messing with your work.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the culprit is [Fanboy's Social Blocking List](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/fanboy-social.txt), which is one of the filter subscriptions included in Adblock Plus. It has already caused me a lot of distress in the past.

To disable it, click on the Adblock Plus toolbar button and choose **Open filter preferences**. You'll then find the list of subscriptions and you can simply unsubscribe to that one.

[image]

It's better than disabling Adblock Plus completely so you can continue using it for what it was originally intended: blocking ads.